# Django post nested serializer by javascript FormData

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, axios, form-data

I have these classes:

```
class LetterModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='user', null=True,
                             blank=True)
    part = models.ForeignKey(OrganisationChartModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='part', null=True,
                             blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    text = models.TextField()
    letter_type = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    confidentiality = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    signer = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='signer', related_name='signer',
                               null=True, blank=True)
    signer_description = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   


class LetterReceiverModel(models.Model):
    letter = models.ForeignKey(LetterModel, related_name='receivers', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               db_column='letter', null=True,
                               blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='user', null=True,
                             blank=True)
    part = models.ForeignKey(OrganisationChartModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='part', null=True,
                             blank=True)

    type = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    external_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    external_part_name = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
```

And serializers:

```
class LetterReceiverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True, default=None, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = LetterReceiverModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['letter']


class LetterDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    receivers = LetterReceiverSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = LetterModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return SerializerFunctions.create(validated_data, LetterModel, 'receivers')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        return SerializerFunctions.update(validated_data, instance, 'receivers')
```

It works well by the postman and this submitted JSON :

```
{
    "receivers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "receiver",
            "comment": ".",
            "deadline": "1401-09-16",
            "seen": false,
            "external_full_name": null,
            "external_part_name": null,
            "user": 3,
            "part": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "receiver",
            "comment": "......",
            "deadline": null,
            "seen": false,
            "external_full_name": null,
            "external_part_name": null,
            "user": 3,
            "part": 2
        }
    ],
    "title": "test",
    "text": ".........",
    "letter_type": "...",
    "priority": ".......",
    "confidentiality": "........",
    "signer_description": "........",
    "created": "2022-11-24T05:53:15.690934Z",
    "user": 3,
    "part": 1,
    "signer": 3
}
```

I tried to send data by javascript FormData and I append the nested values like this:

```
formData.append('receivers',JSON.stringify(this.receivers))
```

But Django didn't detect **receivers** and give this error:

> receivers: [ "This field is required." ]

How I can add nested objects to FormData?

Comment: Shouldn't `formData.append('receiver',JSON.stringify(this.receivers))` be `formData.append('receivers',JSON.stringify(this.receivers))`?

Comment: thankyou for mentioning that. that was a typographical error. @Pablo